# How works android ImageView android:scaleType="fitXY" property?

Tags: android, imageview

I need to know how he takes drawable object.
I'm collecting some ImageView objects in array, they have background images that are rather big in resolution so they take lot of memory... 
I have read somewhere that it will automatically create image with resolution that my imageView have, so i think it will take less memory than first one...
Please tell me, if i set scaleType property, will it scale that image? 
Will that help me to save memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't save you any memory to set the scaleType of the ImageView because the original backing Bitmap will still remain, regardless of which scaling you choose.  Since you can resize or change the scale type dynamically there's no optimization that the ImageView can make with regards to image size.