# What is the best way to resize images within XML

Tags: xml, eclipse

I am new to Android and still learning / having trouble with XML

What is the best way to have images resized within XML.

Currently the width and height of the images are set as

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Which is OK for most screen sizes but anything too big or small and it either fills too much of the screen up or not enough. 
What is the best way to set it so that the image is a set size but scales to whatever screen it is displaying on?
I want it to be a set size for all device sizes not big on one and small on others. I am really struggling with setting things in XML so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view"     
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
  android:maxWidth="42dp"  
  android:maxHeight="42dp"  
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"  
  android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"  
  android:src="@drawable/icon"  
  />
```

Add property android:scaleType="fitCenter" and android:adjustViewBounds="true"

I believe you want to use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

Check this SQ Question : [How works android ImageView android:scaleType="fitXY" property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547084/how-works-android-imageview-androidscaletype-fitxy-property)